# C# WinApi эмулировать нажатие медиакнопок для всех приложений

Tags: c#, winapi, interop

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: пишу универсальный виджет для управления музыкой и хочу сделать так, чтобы работало со всеми нормальными плеерами (VLC, Groove, Itunes).
Решил сделать это через отправку broadcast сообщения всем окнам в системе, но окна их не получают (может тупо игнорят?)

Код:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
private static readonly int HWND_BROADCAST = 0xffff;

private static readonly int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
private static readonly int WM_KEYUP = 0x101;
private static readonly int VK_VOLUME_MUTE = 0xad;
private static readonly int VK_VOLUME_DOWN = 0xae;
private static readonly int VK_VOLUME_UP = 0xaf;
private static readonly int VK_MEDIA_NEXT_TRACK = 0xb0;
private static readonly int VK_MEDIA_PREV_TRACK = 0xb1;
private static readonly int VK_MEDIA_STOP = 0xb2;
private static readonly int VK_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE = 0xb3;

Debug.WriteLine(SendMessage(new IntPtr(HWND_BROADCAST), WM_KEYDOWN, new IntPtr(VK_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE), IntPtr.Zero));
Debug.WriteLine(SendMessage(new IntPtr(HWND_BROADCAST), WM_KEYUP, new IntPtr(VK_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE), IntPtr.Zero));
```

В дебаге оба вызова возвращают 1, следовательно сообщение отправляется.

В чем может быть проблема? Неужели для всех плееров придется дублировать код с поиском дескриптора?

Comment: "Applications that need to communicate using HWND_BROADCAST should use the RegisterWindowMessage function to obtain a unique message for inter-application communication." т.е. `HWND_BROADCAST` не подойдет для Ваших целей

Comment: @mega получается, что нет способов симулировать нажатие клавиши медиа для всех приложений? Сработает ли ужасный перебор процессов с последующей отправкой каждому сообщения о нажатии клавиши PlayPause?

Comment: Для эмуляции клавиш обычно используется `SendInput`. Посмотрите пример тут: [Эмуляция нажатия мультимедийных клавиш в Windows, Linux и Mac OS X](https://habrahabr.ru/post/217779/).

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо!